# Deserialize map of Int to Tuple using Jackson

Tags: json, scala, dictionary, jackson, jackson-module-scala

I have a class that looks something like

```
case class A (id: Int, name: String, marks: Map[Int, List(Long, Long)])
```

I am using Jackson to serialize and store the objects in a database and read them back. 
However, when I deserialize it the Map is `Map[String, List(Int, Int)]`.

I could get the keys deserialized correctly by using
`@JsonDeserialize(keyAs: classOf[Integer])`
but I can't get the values to deserialize correctly.

Comment: Please checkout https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/wiki/FAQ and related examples here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/scala/deser/PrimitiveContainerTest.scala

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama Already visited that link.
I tried `@JsonDeserialize(contentAs: classOf[List[(Long, Long)]])` but it doesn't seem to work